# Most "correct" method to reveal preferences over large set of items

Tags: survey, methodology

That probably is too 'practical' question so I will be happy to re-formulate it in more abstract terms if needed.

I have a list of n items (say, 30) and an audience, larger than n (say, 200). I am interested to know what are the most popular three items among this audience. What is the most correct and efficient way of doing it?

I realize of course that there can be the case of a draw, or some other peculiar distribution of preferences that won't allow me to draw any conclusion. But apart of these unlikely situations, if we assume there **are** top three most preferred items, what could the way to ask the audience the least amount of questions (i.e. *efficiency*) to these three items with the highest probability (i.e *correctness*)?

Comment: Point for clarification: ¿what is the response scale for the $n$ item?

Comment: well, for ranking we don't need the response scale if I get it right? we just need to sort them from 'most preferred to least preferred'. But if we need some scale it can be "on the scale from 0 to 5 how do you like item _n_"

Comment: I'll rephrase:  ¿are you asking respondents to pick their top three (or some other number) from the $n$ choices? or ¿are you asking respondents to rate the entire set of $n$ choices on some scale?

Comment: Or, are you asking participants to rank their favorite items from 1 to 30?

Comment: no, I intend to ask them to choose 3 most liked items out of 30